# Navbar element drops to second line instead of aligning to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap to create a menu bar. My brand label is aligned far left. The main menu options are center aligned. I'm trying to get 'Logout' to be right aligned. But instead, its on a second line and centered.

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: White;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-right {
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>

<body id=<?php echo $bodyid ?>>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Assessment Manager</a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="../public/home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/clients.php">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/contacts.php">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/employees.php">Employees</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/findings.php">Findings</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/projects.php">Projects</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Vulnerabilities<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="../public/hostvulns.php">Host</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../public/webvulns.php">Web</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="../public/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

[See a picture of the menu bar here.](https://imagebin.ca/v/2jgBMheYwCSc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `<ul>` elements in the same container. Also you have a CSS class `navbar-right` that wasn't used in your HTML.  This HTML seems to work fine given a wide enough browser window:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Assessment Manager</a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="../public/home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/clients.php">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/contacts.php">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/employees.php">Employees</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/findings.php">Findings</a></li>
            <li><a href="../public/projects.php">Projects</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Vulnerabilities<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="../public/hostvulns.php">Host</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../public/webvulns.php">Web</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="../public/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You could also experiment with `float:right;` on the `<ul>` for your login link (using the same `navbar-right` class.

Also, keep in mind that bootstrap intends for the container class to have `row` and `col` classes inside it to further wrap the content.  By using only `container` you're missing out on a lot of the responsive behavior bootstrap is intended to provide.